# Não permitir guardar imagem de uma página web

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Eu quero, que não apareça a opção "save image as.." quando clico com o botão direito do rato em cima de uma imagem numa página HTML. Ou seja, vai ser impossível guardar as imagens do site. Como posso fazer esta verificação?

Comment: Teste: abra a página com a imagem. Abra o Paint (no Windows). Aperte alt+tab para o foco voltar para a página. Aperte PrtScr. Aperte alt+tab para voltar ao Paint. Aperte Ctrl+V para colar a imagem. Se a imagem apareceu, o seu método de impedir de salvar a imagem falhou.

Comment: Qualquer pessoa pode salvar as imagens de um site sem precisar do mouse.

Comment: Se você vai vender esta solução a um cliente não há como garantir que ela é à prova de fogo. O utilizador pode gravar a página e/ou abrir com javascript desactivado, pode copiar imagens só com o teclado, pode ir ao cache buscar, etc etc. É melhor aceitar que não é possivel garantir esse comportamento.

Comment: Sempre que uma imagem aparece no navegador ela já esta no teu disco, se tu conseguir bloquear todas as outras formas, ainda tem a opções de baixar pelos arquivos temporários de internet :/

Comment: Aviso que estes procedimentos não impedem realmente o download das imagens, apenas dificulta para quem não entende de html e do uso das ferramentas de desenvolvedor disponíveis nos browsers.

Comment: sim, eu sei disso. Mas o cliente pediu-me que ao clicar com o botão direito, não pudesse guardar a imagem. Isto é apenas para fazer a "vontade" ao cliente

Comment: Marcas d'água parecem a melhor forma de limitação de uso. Há soluções que fazem isso diretamente via Javascript (essa, por exemplo: http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/), mas que ainda assim podem ser burladas por usuários com conhecimento. Se, entretanto, a imagem original já tiver uma marca d'água (feita em Gimp, por exemplo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D953v8dgfj8), fica bem mais difícil de ser utilizada levianamente (ou sem a devida propaganda, como o @utluiz mencionou na resposta dele). Deixe claro para o seu cliente as limitações e vantagens de cada abordagem.

Comment: Ah, e apenas por curiosidade (e porque é beeeemmm legal!), dependendo do seu propósito de exibição (*preview*, por exemplo) e se o projeto permitir ser "criativo", há opções como usar apenas texto para exibir imagens. :) Exemplo: http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/jsascii/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode bloquear o "Clique direito" do mouse em sua página, **porém isto não é recomendável**, pois você perderá todas as outras funcionalidades que o botão direito tem. Mesmo assim, há um meio de fazer, se você realmente quiser, utilizando o seguinte código JavaScript:

```js
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
function disableclick(event)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     return false;    
   }
}
```

**E também você tem que adicionar esta propriedade ao seu `<body>` do seu HTML:**

```html
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

**Informação Adicional:** Muitos navegadores tem uma opção de segurança para não permitir que desativem o "Clique com o Botão Direito do Mouse".

**Detalhe importante:** Referente ao título da sua pergunta... a minha solução não vai impedir que o usuário consiga a sua imagem, porém apenas vai dificultar. (isso se ele esteja com javascript habilitado no navegador.)

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Aviso que este procedimento não impede realmente o download das imagens, apenas dificulta para quem não entende de html e do uso das ferramentas de desenvolvedor disponíveis nos browsers.

Answer (score 13):

Não é possivel bloquear conteúdo ao utilizador. Aliás quando a página abre a imagem já está na cache no computador.

Eu sou (pessoalmente) contra mudar a funcionalidade esperada de um browser/página. Porém, para o tentar ajudar,a melhor opção que vejo é usar as imagens como `background-image` e não como `<img>`.

Outra opção é bloquear a imagem com, por exemplo, uma `div` transparente em cima da imagem para ela não ser receber click, ou com CSS: `pointer-events: none;`.

Existe ainda outra opção que é usar Flash, mas mais uma vez, é sempre possível obter a imagem se o utilizador souber como fazer.

Porém, mais uma vez, o conteudo já está do no computador e é possivel copiá-lo.

Sugestão de **[leitura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446585/disable-save-save-as-option-in-all-browsers-using-javascript)** <sup>(em Inglês)</sup>

Comment: Penso que seja possível, lembro-me que o antigo "hi5" tinha essa protecção, se não estou em erro

Comment: claro que é possivel, vou postar uma resposta

Comment: É possível não ter a opção "Save image as" mas Sérgio está certo. Mesmo sem esta opção a imagem que o usuário está vendo já está no cache do navegador. Se mesmo assim vc ainda quer remover a opção coloque uma div invisível sobre a imagem, dai que o usuário ao tentar clicar na imagem na verdade estará clicando na div.

Comment: mas assim como eu posso não deixar o utilizador copiar o texto, também deve ser possível para as imagens

Comment: A única maneira de você impedir um usuário de copiar o texto é usando uma imagem no lugar do texto, mesmo assim é impossível impedir o usuário de obter a imagem e fazer OCR nela. (a não ser num captcha onde o texto é distorcido para difultar o OCR)

Answer (score 4):

Pode desabilitar o click do botão direito da seguinte forma:

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
  return false;
});
```

[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/wM8Zm/)

Tentou algum plugin?

Tem alguns [AQUI](http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/right-click-context-menu-plugins/).

Comment: já tinha testado este código e também não dá

Comment: não deve dar devido algum javascript que já lá tenha. obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 4):

Alguns sites como o Flickr, sites de fotógrafos, artesanato e outros possuem alguns mecanismos de proteção para evitar que *uma pessoa qualquer sem experiência com computadores* salvem as fotos disponibilizadas. Infelizmente, pessoas de caráter duvidoso copiam essas fotos e republicam como se fossem os autores.

Alguns sites usam javascript para tentar bloquear o menu de contexto e a seleção do conteúdo do site. Outros colocam um *layer* transparente por cima da imagem para evitar o menu de contexto. Há os que usem tecnologias como Flash para exibir as imagens em um *container* controlado.

Em minha experiência, qualquer uma dessas técnicas tem dois impactos maiores e imediatos:

- De fato, vai dificultar que pessoas sem conhecimento em computadores salvem as imagens, principalmente as que usam Internet Explorer, o navegador que permite maior a maior intrusão de código alheio.
- Porém, vai diminuir grandemente a usabilidade do site para usuários legítimos.

Quando eu acesso um site, clico com o botão direto e aparece uma caixa de diálogo com uma mensagem tipo "Cópia proibida", minha primeira reação é: tentar procurar um site melhor. Se não tiver escolha, o próximo passo é desabilitar o Script.

Em minha experiência, a única forma "segura" e "legítima" para garantir direitos sobre as imagens é colocar um logotipo ou marca d'água na própria imagem.

Minhas sugestões são:

- Não tente inibir o usuário. As melhores empresas e os melhores negócios são aqueles que focam no cliente e não na proteção dos seus próprios direitos.
- Use meios mais criativos para evitar as cópias. Há vários anos quando era webdesigner, fiz vários sites de artesanato. A melhor coisa era colocar logotipo com o link do site nas imagens e deixar todo mundo copiar. Assim o site ganhava muita divulgação gratuita com pessoas que mandavam as fotos para amigos.

Answer (score 2):

Sobreponha uma div invisível sobre a imagem, ao tentar clicar na imagem o usuário estará clicando na div. Porém veja a resposta do Sérgio, ele está certo.

Answer (score 1):

Se vai estar na web, vai ser bem difícil você proibir que um usuário não salve a imagem. Com um simples print, da pra burlar isso. Acho que não é possível impedir o usuário de fazer algo errado. Podemos sim limitar suas **macro ações**.

Exemplos de **macro ações**:

**Está "solução" bloqueia a cópia de conteúdo da página inteira, você pode usar esse script trocando o Document pelo ID ou pela CLASS do seu componente**

- Bloquear o CTRL+A
- Menu de contexto com o botão direito
- Selecionar texto com o mouse

```jquery
 function block() {
        jQuery.fn.extend({
            disableSelection : function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    this.onselectstart = function() {
                        return false;
                    };
                    this.unselectable = "on";
                    jQuery(this).css('user-select', 'none');
                    jQuery(this).css('-o-user-select', 'none');
                    jQuery(this).css('-moz-user-select', 'none');
                    jQuery(this).css('-khtml-user-select', 'none');
                    jQuery(this).css('-webkit-user-select', 'none');
                });
            },
            disableSelectedAll : function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    this.onkeydown = function(event) {
                        if( event.ctrlKey \\&\\& (event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 97) ){
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    };
                });
            }
        });

        $(document).disableSelection();

        $(document).disableSelectedAll();

        $(document).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
```

> Fonte: [Atitude Refletiva](http://atitudereflexiva.wordpress.com/tag/javascript/)

Comment: sim, eu sei que é possível com o printscreen. Mas o cliente pediu-me que ao clicar com o botão direito, não pudesse guardar a imagem.

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é dificultar as opções fornecidas irão te ajudar. Porém o que está trafegando na net não está protegido, ou seja, na requisição Http a imagem está lá.

No firefox se você acessar `Ferramenta-> Propiedade da Página-> Mídia` lá ira ter as imagens que a página está utilizando. Ou até mesmo acessar a `Ferramenta de Desenvolvedor`que todos os Browsers hoje possuem.

Comment: eu sei disso, mas o cliente pediu para não aparecer o "save image as.."

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível fazer isso via código, vai ter que encontrar outra saída para fazer isso. Por exemplo colocar um **div** em cima da imagem com as mesma dimenções. Assim quando ele clicar não vai aparecer a opção de salvar 'save image as'..