# Dê uma alternativa de bloqueio do botão direito sobre uma image

Tags: javascript

Quais formas podemos **ocultar o caminho de uma image** se o usuário clicar sobre ela **com o botão direito do mouse**?

Comment: Outras sobre o mesmo assunto [Bloquear acesso ao código fonte de um site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81546/70) e [Não permitir guardar imagem de uma página web](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4537/70)

Comment: Reverti a edição, pois mudou completamente a pergunta. Sempre que tiver uma dúvida diferente e a pergunta já foi respondida, faça uma pergunta separada, senão prejudica respostas já existentes.

Answer (score 1):

Usando jQuery:

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zzw216du/

Fonte:
*[Disabling right click on images using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery)*